# Nested z-index inside relative elements

Tags: html, css

I'm facing an issue where I need to position the `.arrow` element on top of all layers within my HTML structure without making any changes to the structure itself. Despite setting z-index values, the .arrow element isn't displaying as intended. I've included the relevant HTML and CSS code below for reference.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.background {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="arrow"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried adjusting the `z-index` values to control the stacking order, but the .arrow element isn't consistently displaying above all layers. Is there a solution to achieve this stacking order without modifying the existing HTML structure? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at MDN page for [Stacking Contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context)

I won't go into the details, this is a complex topic, but the summary of it is that when a stacking context is created (in your case by having you `.wrapper` positionned and with a `z-index`), all the child element's z-index will be relative to the parent's z-index. It means that by setting `z-index: 3;` for your arrow it is not considered in an absolute manner, global to the page, but relative to its parent with `z-index: 2;`

You already see in your snippet that the `.background` is already on top of the `.wrapper`. It means that it will be also on top of its children.

You can lower the z-index for `.background` to 1 for example so that it doesn't go on top of `.wrapper` to start with.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.background {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="arrow"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```